# Azure Devops pipelines and multiple project docker

Tags: .net, azure, docker, azure-pipelines

I'm giving my first steps in DevOps.

**SCENARIO**

I've setup a very simple/silly example app. As you can see in the picture, the solution contains 4 .net core APIS with it's Dockerfile and at the solution level there is a docker-compose.yml file. All of dockerfiles and docker-compose files were added using the visual studio for mac ide.

My goal is publish each image to the Azure Container Registry (ACR) using Azure Devops Pipelines.

[image: overview]

**THE CODE**

the source code can be found at [this repo](https://github.com/holden-ar/a-tiny-dockerizable-project)

**THE PROBLEM**

In my local dev environment everything works great, if I type docker *compose up I* can play around with all of the APIs.

The problem arise when running [my azure devops pipeline](https://github.com/holden-ar/a-tiny-dockerizable-project/blob/main/pipelines/AdditionApi.yml) I'm receiving

> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by
> .dockerignore: stat Services/AdditionAPI/AdditionAPI.csproj: file does
> not exist

I've notice many devs face this problem but I don't understand the correct way to solve it since I would like to keep my local dev env integrated with the IDE and easy to debug, and of course, pipelines for building and releasing.

I would really appreciate if a kind soul could take some minutes to explain the solution and its point of view.

Thanks all in advance.

**TROUBLE SHOOTING**

1- I've added as suggested in line 16

```
 dockerfilePath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Services/AdditionAPI/Dockerfile'
```

2- I've added an extra step to see the folder structure of the agent

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |         
      echo "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory:" 
      
      echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      
      echo "Build.BinariesDirectory:" 
      
      echo "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
      
      echo "Build.SourcesDirectory:"
      
      echo "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"

       echo "Structure of work folder of this pipeline:"
      tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)
```

3- I've received this error

```
##[error]COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat Services/AdditionAPI/AdditionAPI.csproj: file does not exist
> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by
```

> .dockerignore: stat Services/AdditionAPI/AdditionAPI.csproj: file does
> not exist

4- And the folder structure is

```html
/home/vsts/work
├── 1
│   ├── TestResults
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── s
│       ├── DockerCompose.yml
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── img
│       │   └── overview.png
│       ├── pipelines
│       │   ├── DockerCompose.yml
│       │   └── SubstractionApiImg.yml
│       └── src
│           ├── ClientGateway
│           │   ├── ClientGateway.csproj
│           │   ├── Ocelot.json
│           │   ├── Program.cs
│           │   ├── Properties
│           │   │   └── launchSettings.json
│           │   ├── appsettings.Development.json
│           │   ├── appsettings.json
│           │   └── web.config
│           ├── Services
│           │   ├── AdditionAPI
│           │   │   ├── AdditionAPI.csproj
│           │   │   ├── Commands
│           │   │   │   └── AdditionCommand.cs
│           │   │   ├── Controllers
│           │   │   │   └── IntegerOperationController.cs
│           │   │   ├── Dockerfile
```

As we can see Dockerfile is there...

5. This is the current Docker action:

```html
- task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: src/Services/AdditionAPI/Dockerfile
        buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Services/AdditionAPI
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Comment: Please don't include links to assets, include the actual text. This question will not be useful to future visitors if you remove the repository in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `buildContext` parameter to ensure that your `docker build` command is running out of the correct subdirectory. The root of the cloned repo will be in the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` system variable. Proceed from there. Something like `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Services/AdditionAPI` will probably work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Daniel Mann, I've changed line 16 of the pipeline to dockerfilePath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Services/AdditionAPI/Dockerfile' but it seems not to ben finding the Dockerfile. Notice the new step I've  added to see the folder structure of the agent.

Comment: @HoracioValdez I didn't recommend that you change the `dockerFilePath` parameter. That was fine. I recommended that you set the `buildContext` parameter.

Comment: Same error...  I pasted the piepline code into the the point #5 of troubleshooting. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Your `dockerfile` is looking for the path `Services/AdditionAPI/AdditionAPI.csproj`. So your build context should be `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/`.

Comment: That was the key, the path in dockerfile! thanks you for taking the time to answer this question.